# How to refer to the files in subdirectory in shell program?

Tags: shell

I have a script called idk.sh at the root of a folder called autograder.
I also have a subdirectory in autograder called hw1 which contains some .sh files. I tried to print out the file name and contents but I failed. actually I tried /hw1, /hw1/, /hw1/* and failed. I dont really understand why I failed to fetch files and hope someone could answer me as I looked up the web and found that the approach should be /hw1/*. Thank you.

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in /hw1/*
do
        echo $file
        if [ -f $file ]
        then
                cat $file
                echo $file
        fi
done
~
~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply do a `find` to achieve this

```
find /hw/ -type f -print -exec cat {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

A directory path starting with `/` means an *absolute* path, that is, a path from the root of the filesystem. *Relative* paths start with any character other than `/` (and `\0`, but that's a technicality). You'll also want to use a reference to [the directory of the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in), to be able to run the script from other directories.

See also:

- [How do I determine the location of my script?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)
- [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)
- [Linux Filesystem Tree Overview](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview)